# XML Schema, XML error

Tags: xml, validation

Hello I have problem with XML-XML Schema. XML is well-formed, XML Schema too. But when I try validate XML wit XML Schema some errot occured. What I am doing bad? I have attached my XML and XML schema. Thank You for your help.

I am using : http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/
there occured Error: [PIC](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35284336/eror.JPG)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <xs:element name="library">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="book"/>
     <xs:element name="book_id" type="xs:integer"/>
     <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="count" type="xs:integer"/>
     <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<library>
  <book>
    <book_id>5</book_id>
    <title>Sokak</title>
    <author>Tony</author>
    <count>6</count>
    <genre>epic</genre>
  </book>
  <book>
    <book_id>13</book_id>
    <title>Kucharka</title>
    <author>Fiona</author>
    <count>8</count>
    <genre>Hobby</genre>
  </book>
</library>
```

Comment: You could have posted the error: **Not valid.
Error - Line 2, 12: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 12; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'library'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the schema defines a `targetNamespace` that is not used in your document namely `http://www.w3schools.com`. Try adding changing your document like:

```
<library xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <!-- ... -->
</library>
```

Second the schema defines a sequence of elements whereas your document contains a nested structure. If you want a nested structure adjust the schema like in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:w3s="http://www.w3schools.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:complexType name="bookType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="book_id" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="count" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="libraryType">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="book" type="w3s:bookType" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="library" type="w3s:libraryType" />

</xs:schema>
```